# Sefardim starting to study the Talmud with Rashi and Tosfot

Tags: history, torah-study, talmud-gemara, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, commentaries

When did the sefardim start to study the Talmud with Rashi and Tosfot? And which books did they use before knowing about Rashi and Tosfot?